# Efficiently order by columns from different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

We're currently trying to improve a system that allows the user to filter and sort a large list of objects (> 100k) by fields that are not being displayed. Since the fields can be selected dynamically we'd plan to build the query dynamically as well.

That doesn't sound too hard and the basics are done easily but the problem lies in how the data is structured. In some cases some more or less expensive joins would be needed which could some up to a quite expensive query, especially when those joins are combined (i.e. `select * from table join some_expensive_join join another_expensive_join ...`).

Filtering wouldn't be that big a problem since we can use intersections.

Ordering, however, would require us to first build a table that contains all necessary data which if being done via a huge select statement with all those joins would become quite expensive.

So the question is: is there a more efficient way to do that?

I could think of doing it like this:

- do a select query for the first column and order by that
- for all elements that basically have the same order (e.g. same value) do another query to resolve that
- repeat the step above until the order is unambiguous or we run out of sort criteria

Does that make sense? If yes, how could this be done in Postgresql 9.4 (we currently can't upgrade so 9.5+ solutions though welcome wouldn't help as right now).

Comment: This is just a rule of thumb, but usually it is most efficient to do everything in one query, i.e. `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT .. FROM ... JOIN ... INTERSECT SELECT ...) q ORDER BY ...`. The biggest problem in such a setup usually is to keep people from using too few restrictive criteria, which makes execution time and the result set explode.

Comment: don't you unavoidably sort the huge set at the end?.. either by original columns, or by presorted column sum? but any way building the order based on "smaller" orders will require ordering on the whole set. Sorry if I'm suggesting nonsence - I just don't see how you can avoid the huge sort if you need the set ordered

Comment: `... but the problem lies in how the data is structured...` How **is** it structured?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe actually our approach would be something like this, i.e. `select ... from (filter query using intersections) join (whatever is needed to sort) order by` - the question aims at how that "join (whatever is needed to sort)" part could be optimized.

Comment: @VaoTsun Ideally we'd be able to sort the entire (pre-filtered) set using one column only or 2 at max (let's say we sort products by price and name). So if one column would already result in an unambiguos order we'd like to not have to add any additional joins or execute other (potentially expensive) queries that won't change the result. - Hope that makes sense. :)

Comment: @wildplasser well, the data is quite normalized and spread over a couple of tables. That could result in multiple joins (could be 5 or more in some cases) just to get _one_ column that we want to sort by. Additionally some data would actually represent a list inside the object and ordering would happen by comparing the lists element by element (e.g. let's say we want to sort products which can have multiple colors by color: we'd compare the colors at index 0 first, then index 1 etc.). - We could reorganize the data, e.g. use array types, jsonb etc., but that might be even more work.

Comment: @Thomas sorry to be a stubborn, but you sort data on display. if you presort it before join - after join will be unsorted again - that's why I think you have to sort the whole bunch despite any action. Also maybe please postg some structure and samples?.. I played with pg_catalog joins and came to conclusion I can't beat optimyzer

Comment: @VaoTsun hmm, I'm not sure how much I'm allowed to post or how good a simplified example would be. Additionally I'm not sure I understand you correctly but of course I'd sort the data in the last step(s). I realize that adding data afterwards would destroy the order so what I thought about would be something like a recursive approach, i.e. while ordering queries to load add are executed when needed (maybe something like a function).

Comment: So the *shape* of the outer query is (more or less) fixed, while the (not selected) `order by` terms are variable, and stem from a variable set of tables or subqueries ?

Comment: @wildplasser yes, basically the current plan (because it would best fit the rest of the system) is to have the query return a list of filtered and ordered ids which then are chunked per page and used to load the actual display data.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help, or is it too trivial? (the subqueries could be prefab join views)

---

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.a,t0.b,t0.c, ...
FROM main_table t0
JOIN ( SELECT t1.id AS id
        , rank() OVER (ORDER BY whatever) AS rnk
        FROM different_tables_or_JOINS
        ) AS t1 ON t1.id=t0.id

JOIN ( SELECT t2.id AS id
        , rank() OVER (ORDER BY whatever) AS rnk
        FROM different_tables_or_JOINS2
        ) AS t2 ON t2.id=t0.id

        ...

ORDER BY t1.rnk
        , t2.rnk
        ...
        , t0.id
        ;
```

Comment: I had same idea, but - on pg_catalog joins such tripple `order by` was 74 ms angainst 73 ms without `ORDER BY` in subqueries, but just order by original columns

Comment: I didn't know about `rank()` but that seems like a way to at least reduce the data that needs to be moved around. Thanks for that.